# Heroville academy breaks upgrades?

Tags: heroville

On the default Android browser I no longer seem to be able to spend gold on upgrades. It's been like this since I got the academy. 
Is there a way I can fix it?

*(Game is currently version 1.0)*

Comment: It does seem Academy is bugged as I had that issue as well when playing on a small window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrades seem to be broken in the current version due to some screen resizing and the effect of the academy upgrade.

In the next version the upgrade system is being overhauled and should be in a better location.

Comment: Do you get this information from a post somewhere? Not that I don't believe you, I'm just wondering where I could see more information about the game's development.

Comment: I am the developer ;) and I have received a few reports about some issues with upgrades after the academy is unlocked :)